# How do I execute a .bat file through COMMAND in CMAKE that has spaces in it's path

Tags: batch-file, cmd, cmake

I am trying to execute a simple .bat file through a CMake script via the execute_process macro. So far I have tried these three:

```
execute_process(COMMAND cmd /c "E:/dev/test folder with spaces/test with spaces.bat")
execute_process(COMMAND cmd /c "\"E:/dev/test folder with spaces/test with spaces.bat\"")
execute_process(COMMAND cmd /c [=["E:/dev/test folder with spaces/test with spaces.bat"]=])
```

None of them work, the output looks like this:

```
'E:/dev/test' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'\"E:/dev/test folder with spaces/test with spaces.bat\"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'\"E:/dev/test folder with spaces/test with spaces.bat\"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The Windows path separator is `\ `but not `/`! Anyway, `cmd.exe` can be a bit tricky when itz comes to quotes, but you could try `cmd /C ""E:\dev\test folder with spaces\test with spaces.bat""`, or also `cmd /C call "E:\dev\test folder with spaces\test with spaces.bat"` (`call` is not needed but does not harm, it is just here to avoid the first character to be a quote)…

Comment: I finally rebooted into Windows. Your first attempt ought to work. What version of CMake are you running? I cannot reproduce on CMake 3.20.4 or 3.21.1

Comment: I updated the 3.21.1 and the issue seems to be gone! Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to reproduce your issue. I recreated your example in my `D:` drive (I don't have `E:`).

```
D:\>tree /F "test folder with spaces"
Folder PATH listing for volume Sources
Volume serial number is 000000DD 943F:828D
D:\TEST FOLDER WITH SPACES
    test with spaces.bat

No subfolders exist
```

In `D:\test folder with spaces\test with spaces.bat`, I put the following little script:

```
@echo off
echo Success!
```

Then I created a test script `test.cmake` in `D:\test.cmake`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

execute_process(
  COMMAND cmd /C "D:/test folder with spaces/test with spaces.bat"
)
```

and I ran it and see this:

```
D:\>cmake -P test.cmake
Success!
```

All I can infer is that you're using a very old version of CMake and that you should upgrade.